# Is energy only the change in spacetime of an object with respect to an observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, spacetime, faq

It is fact that there is only kinetic energy that is eligible to do some work. Even the, EM energies are the kinetic energy of quantum particles such as photons. Kinetic energy for an well defined particle is an variant only if its velocity changes or simply accelerates (or decelerates). The velocity of an particle can be defined as the change of its space as the time changes or change in its spacetime respect to an observer. So my question is, Is energy only the change in spacetime of an object with respect to an observer?

It seems to be correct. I am aware about the facts that seems to be correct but these aren't correct at all. So please aware me if my imagination is wrong or right with good explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is fact that there is only kinetic energy that is eligible to do some work. Even the, EM energies are the kinetic energy of quantum particles such as photons.

This is simply incorrect, and starting with this incorrect premise may be the reason for your confusion.

Gravitational potential energy and electrostatic potential energy are both examples of non-kinetic energy that is eligible to do work. In a purely electrostatic field (as opposed to a dynamic electromagnetic field) there are no real photons with the usual KE and momentum relationship typical of photons (i.e. on shell).

> The velocity of an particle can be defined as the change of its space as the time changes or change in its spacetime respect to an observer.

I have never seen any example where any professional physicist refers to the velocity of a particle as the "change in its spacetime". I would not recommend using this terminology as it is almost guaranteed to cause confusion.

> So my question is, Is energy only the change in spacetime of an object with respect to an observer?

Replacing the strange terminology "change in spacetime" with the standard terminology "velocity" this question becomes:

"Is energy only the velocity of an object with respect to an observer?"

The answer is an emphatic "No"! Energy is not only the velocity of an object with respect to an observer. Even kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ which includes mass as well as velocity. So this idea does not work even strictly for kinetic energy. However, as mentioned above, energy is more than just kinetic energy.

The usual way to define energy is through [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). This is probably the single most important theoretical result in all of physics. Noether's theorem shows that continuous symmetries of the action result in a conserved quantity. In the case of energy, [energy is the conserved quantity due to the time-translation symmetry of the action](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/%7Ekleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-7-conslaw.pdf).

A typical Lagrangian of a point particle of mass $m$ in a potential $V$ would be $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2 - V(x)$$ this Lagrangian is time invariant, so applying Noether's theorem gives the conserved energy $$H=\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2 + V(x)$$ which is not just the velocity $\dot x$, it also includes the mass $m$ and the potential energy $V$

Comment: Can we consider gravity as energy according to general relativity?

Answer (score 0):

I can give the answer in context of only relativity. In it, we turn momentum and energy into one object named the four-momentum. The way we do this is to fit energy as the component of four momentum in the time direction.

Now in different frames, this component would be a different quantity as in each frame this vector takes different components in its representation with the frame's basis

Comment: I don't understand how does this post answer my question?

Comment: The point is that in the relativity case one must abandon the normal conception of ideas like velocity momentum etc as three vectors. @DebanjanBiswas

Comment: Ah yes the classic no explanation dv